# Model::create() method considers only the original request value when creating a record

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a record by passing the request object as an array like

```
    User::create($request->toArray());
```

This works fine and the record is created in the table.

But I need to manipulate a field before creating the record,

```
    $request->password = bcrypt($request->password);

    //echo $request->password;
    User::create($request->toArray());
```

This does not work and the record created in the table still has the old unencrypted value.
I can confirm that `$request->password` does have the encrypted value. There seems to be something going on in `$request->toArray()` call.

*What am I missing here?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change Request object, but you can do this:

```
User::create(['password' => bcrypt($request->password)] + $request->all());
```

But a better approach is to use a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for `password` property:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Then just do this:

```
User::create($request->all());
```

Comment: I am also using the built-in Auth setup provided by Laravel so adding the mutator would mess up things during registration, doesn't it?. But your first solution works!. Thanks

Comment: @SapneshNaik in this case just update the `RegisterController@create` method. Change it to `return User::create($data);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `array_merge` add the `password` to the `$request->toArray()`

```
$password = bcrypt($request->password);

$data = array_merge($request->toArray(), compact('password'))

User::create($data);
```